# Convert complex list of dictionaries into dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
ip_purchase = [
               {
                'V_TYPE': 'Purchase', 'V_No': '1', 'DATE': '20230401', 
                'ITEMS': [{'NAME': 'A100', 'AMOUNT': '-10000.00'}]
               },
               
               {
                'V_TYPE': 'Purchase', 'V_No': '2', 'DATE': '20230401', 
                'ITEMS': [{'NAME': 'RTX A6000', 'AMOUNT': '-50000.00'},
                          {'NAME': 'Jetson Nano', 'AMOUNT': '-4000.00'},
                          {'NAME': 'V100', 'AMOUNT': '-45000.00'}]
               },

               {
                'V_TYPE': 'Purchase', 'V_No': '3', 'DATE': '20230401', 
                'ITEMS': [{'NAME': 'A100', 'AMOUNT': '-10000.00'},
                          {'NAME': 'V100', 'AMOUNT': '-45000.00'}]
               },

              ]
```

I want to convert the above list of dictionaries to a dataframe as follows:

| V_TYPE | V_NO | DATE | ITEMS | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Purchase | 1 | 2023401 | A100 | -10000 |
| Purchase | 2 | 2023401 | RTX A6000 | -50000 |
| Purchase | 2 | 2023401 | Jetson Nano | -4000 |
| Purchase | 2 | 2023401 | V100 | -45000 |
| Purchase | 3 | 2023401 | A100 | -10000 |
| Purchase | 3 | 2023401 | V100 | -45000 |

I know I can use the `to_dict()` function to convert a list of dictionaries to a dataframe but the nested list in the `ITEMS` is messing up the format. the `ip_purchase` list can have any number of elements (i.e. dictionaries) and the nested `ITEMS` list can also have any number of elements (i.e. dictionaries).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

one way would be by flattening nested list of dictionaries as below

```py
result = []
for ip in ip_purchase:
    v_type = ip['V_TYPE']
    v_no = ip['V_No']
    date = ip['DATE']
    for item in ip['ITEMS']:
        name = item['NAME']
        amount = item['AMOUNT']
        result.append({'V_TYPE': v_type, 'V_No': v_no, 'DATE': date, 'ITEMS': name, 'AMOUNT': amount})

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df['AMOUNT'] = pd.to_numeric(df['AMOUNT'])
df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].astype(int)
```

another way would be using json_normalize

```
df = pd.json_normalize(ip_purchase, record_path='ITEMS', meta=['V_TYPE', 'V_No', 'DATE'])
df.rename(columns={'NAME': 'ITEMS'}, inplace=True)
df = df[['V_TYPE', 'V_No', 'DATE', 'ITEMS', 'AMOUNT']]
df['AMOUNT'] = pd.to_numeric(df['AMOUNT'])
df['AMOUNT'] = df['AMOUNT'].astype(int)
```

above two scenarios give the below output:

```
 V_TYPE V_No      DATE        ITEMS  AMOUNT
0  Purchase    1  20230401         A100  -10000
1  Purchase    2  20230401    RTX A6000  -50000
2  Purchase    2  20230401  Jetson Nano   -4000
3  Purchase    2  20230401         V100  -45000
4  Purchase    3  20230401         A100  -10000
5  Purchase    3  20230401         V100  -45000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `json_normalize`

```
pd.json_normalize(ip_purchase, meta=['V_TYPE', 'V_No', 'DATE'], record_path=['ITEMS'])
```

---

```
          NAME     AMOUNT    V_TYPE V_No      DATE
0         A100  -10000.00  Purchase    1  20230401
1    RTX A6000  -50000.00  Purchase    2  20230401
2  Jetson Nano   -4000.00  Purchase    2  20230401
3         V100  -45000.00  Purchase    2  20230401
4         A100  -10000.00  Purchase    3  20230401
5         V100  -45000.00  Purchase    3  20230401
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this task

1. we can use pandas library using json_normalize() function which has
   some parameter

---

```
ip_purchase = [
        {
                'V_TYPE': 'Purchase', 'V_No': '1', 'DATE': '20230401',
                'ITEMS': [{ 'NAME': 'A100', 'AMOUNT': '-10000.00' }]
        },
        {
                'V_TYPE': 'Purchase', 'V_No': '2', 'DATE': '20230401',
                'ITEMS': [{ 'NAME': 'RTX A6000', 'AMOUNT': '-50000.00' },
                { 'NAME': 'Jetson Nano', 'AMOUNT': '-4000.00' },
                { 'NAME': 'V100', 'AMOUNT': '-45000.00' }]
        },
        {
                'V_TYPE': 'Purchase', 'V_No': '3', 'DATE': '20230401',
                'ITEMS': [{ 'NAME': 'A100', 'AMOUNT': '-10000.00' },
                { 'NAME': 'V100', 'AMOUNT': '-45000.00' }]
        }
]
from pandas import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(ip_purchase, meta = ['V_TYPE', 'V_No', 'DATE'], record_path = ['ITEMS']) 
print(df)
```

---

**output**

```
          NAME     AMOUNT    V_TYPE   V_No  DATE
0         A100  -10000.00  Purchase    1  20230401
1    RTX A6000  -50000.00  Purchase    2  20230401
2  Jetson Nano   -4000.00  Purchase    2  20230401
3         V100  -45000.00  Purchase    2  20230401
4         A100  -10000.00  Purchase    3  20230401
5         V100  -45000.00  Purchase    3  20230401
```

Comment: IMO no difference from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76844596/14909621). You've used the same operation twice, passing parameters as positional or named.

Comment: yeah, I was testing into my local, so maybe by mistake I did this, first by defining the parameter, second was giving the values as in the order

Comment: You mentioned different ways. So what other ideas do you have on the topic?

Comment: this is the way, that I have mentioned you will take less time as compared to another approach, that's why I gave you my best approach to get the result,
your one vote will encourage me to help more person also,
I am new in StackOverflow also.

Comment: What do you mean by _less time as compared to another approach_? What _other approach_ are you referring to?

Comment: I have tested into local, you can give one upvote, it motivate me to help more

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) is the tool to use here, as [shown by Shubham Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76844596/14909621). As an alternative:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ip_purchase).explode('ITEMS')
items = df['ITEMS'].apply(pd.Series)
pd.concat([df.drop('ITEMS', axis=1), items], axis=1)
```

Here is the reasoning to choose this way: **what if we have no id for each record in the original data?**

We can surely see here the column `"V_No"` which seems to identify records by a unique number. But if there's no `V_no` values or those values have duplicates, then with `json_normalize` we lose the track of records. While with the approach I mentioned we still have an opportunity to identify their origin by index:

[image: output with different indexes]